# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data_engine'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, module

I am following a tutorial in keras but i am getting the error which i could not find the

documentation online

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data_engine'

What is the problem here does that mean this library is not exist or what?

Comment: You know, we cannot really guess what data_engine is, or if its a package, or how it should be installed, you should provide that information, at least give a link to the tutorial or code.

Answer (score 0):

It means you didn't include the module named 'data_engine', you need to include it at the header of your python script.

Comment: yea but still same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try executing on command prompt

```
pip install data_engine
```

or

```
python3 -m pip install data_engine
```

Comment: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement data_engine (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for data_engin